# How to use custom Tensorflow Lite model

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am very new to machine learning. I have a python file with a very simple TensorFlow model that I need to deploy on Android using Google's ML Kit (which would be creating tflite file). I absolutely don't understand what should be the structure of my python file and Google's documentation doesn't make it any easier. Maybe someone has a good example of converting CUSTOM MODEL WRITTEN FROM SCRATCH and then using it in Java. I need to pass a string from Android's text field and get a predicted answer.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your model and the problem which you are facing? You may refer [this](https://proandroiddev.com/classifying-doodles-on-android-with-tensorflow-lite-be0afcf94450) and [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/use-custom-models).

Comment: You need to create a .tflite file with `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter` API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first train your model on whatever the dataset you have. The layers in the model must comply with the supported layers by the TFLite library. Here is a [list](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_compatibility) of layers that are supported and unsupported.

Once you have trained it, based on how you saved it (Let's say using `kerasmodel.save`). Convert it to TFLite following this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api#converting_a_keras_model_) or other tutorials on this page.

Now you can use this `.tflite` model in Android studio. For this you can follow this good [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/spam-classification-in-android-with-tensorflow-lite-cde417e81260).